# Magento 2 How to fillter using custom product attribute in searchCriteriaBuilder?

Tags: magento2

I am trying to get filter product list by some custom product attribute it gives an error like

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::getEntityPkName() must be an instance of Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity, instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Flat given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php on line 1401 and defined in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php:1634 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php(1401): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection->getEntityPkName(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Flat)) #1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php(1515): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection->_addAttributeJoin('custom_attribute...', 'left') #2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php(1598): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection->_getAttributeConditionSql('custom_attribute...', Array, 'left')
```

My Code :

```
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('custom_attribute', $custom_attribute, 'eq')->create();
```

Is there any error in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the filterBuilder dependency in your code like below:

```
\Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder

$filter = $filterBuilder
            ->setField('custom_attribute')
            ->setValue($custom_attribute)
            ->create();
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters([$filter])->create();
```

Comment: i tried same but it not working with flat catalog.